# Drools 6.0.3 rules - Why this code runs in infinite loop?

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, rules, expert-system

I'm trying to show some messages when a sick person has a diagnosis. The rule to show this is "Imprime diagnosticos"
The problem here is that this code doesn't show any print message... and runs in in infinite loop.

```
package com.sample

rule "sem sintomas 1"
salience 100
when
    $p : Paciente()
    forall($s : Sintomas(idPessoa != $p.getId()))
then
    $p.setDiagnostico("sem sintomas definidos");
    update($p);
end

rule "sem sintomas 2"
salience 90
when
    $s1 : Sintomas(sintoma == "dores")
    $s2 : Sintomas(sintoma == "manchas")
    $p : Paciente(id == $s1.getIdPessoa(), id == $s2.getIdPessoa(), diagnostico == "")
then
    $p.setDiagnostico("sem sintomas definidos");
    update($p);
end

rule "gripe"
salience 60
when
    $s1 : Sintomas(sintoma == "febre")
    $s2 : Sintomas(sintoma == "dores")
    $p : Paciente(id == $s1.getIdPessoa(), id == $s2.getIdPessoa(), diagnostico == "")
then
    $p.setDiagnostico("gripe");
    update($p);
end

rule "enxatema 1"
salience 80
when
    $s1 : Sintomas(sintoma == "febre")
    $s2 : Sintomas(sintoma == "dores")
    $s3 : Sintomas(sintoma == "manchas")
    $p : Paciente(id == $s1.getIdPessoa(), id == $s2.getIdPessoa(), id == $s3.getIdPessoa(), diagnostico == "", idade >= 15)
then
    $p.setDiagnostico("enxatema");
    update($p);
end

rule "enxatema 2"
salience 70
when
    $s1 : Sintomas(sintoma == "febre")
    $s2 : Sintomas(sintoma == "manchas")
    $p : Paciente(id == $s1.getIdPessoa(), id == $s2.getIdPessoa(), diagnostico == "", idade < 15)
then
    $p.setDiagnostico("enxatema");
    update($p);
end

rule "resfriado"
salience 50
when
    $s1 : Sintomas(sintoma == "febre")
    $p : Paciente(id == $s1.getIdPessoa(), diagnostico == "")
then
    $p.setDiagnostico("resfriado");
    update($p);
end

rule "Imprime diagnosticos"
salience 40
when
    $s : Sintomas()
    $p : Paciente(id == $s.getIdPessoa(), diagnostico != "")
then
    System.out.println("Paciente " + $p.getNome() + " com diagnóstico: " + $p.getDiagnostico());
end
```

Here's the Java program inserting the facts:

```
package com.sample;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

public class DroolsTest {

public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // load up the knowledge base
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

        // go !
        Paciente p1 = new Paciente("001", "Ana Melo", "", 33);
        Paciente p2 = new Paciente("002", "Rui Costa", "", 13);
        Paciente p3 = new Paciente("003", "Joana Martins", "", 85);
        Paciente p4 = new Paciente("004", "Pedro Torres","", 53);
        Paciente p5 = new Paciente("005", "Ana Gomes", "", 93);
        Paciente p6 = new Paciente("006", "Jorge Costa", "", 56);

        Sintomas s1 = new Sintomas("001", "febre");
        Sintomas s2 = new Sintomas("001", "dores");
        Sintomas s3 = new Sintomas("001", "manchas");
        Sintomas s4 = new Sintomas("002", "febre");
        Sintomas s5 = new Sintomas("002", "manchas");
        Sintomas s6 = new Sintomas("003", "febre");
        Sintomas s7 = new Sintomas("003", "dores");
        Sintomas s8 = new Sintomas("004", "febre");
        Sintomas s9 = new Sintomas("006", "manchas");
        Sintomas s10 = new Sintomas("006", "dores");

        kSession.insert(p1);
        kSession.insert(p2);
        kSession.insert(p3);
        kSession.insert(p4);
        kSession.insert(p5);
        kSession.insert(p6);

        kSession.insert(s1);
        kSession.insert(s2);
        kSession.insert(s3);
        kSession.insert(s4);
        kSession.insert(s5);
        kSession.insert(s6);
        kSession.insert(s7);
        kSession.insert(s8);
        kSession.insert(s9);
        kSession.insert(s10);
        kSession.fireAllRules();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

public class Paciente {
  private String id, nome, diagnostico;
  private int idade;
  //...
}

public class Sintomas {
  private String idPessoa, sintoma;
  //...
}
```

Thanks for all the help,

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/H13Ct4GV)
[link](http://pastebin.com/VP04F0PG)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at this helpful article [MCVE] on how to present a question that is relatively easy to help with.

Comment: Don't use links to pastebin & Co. They'll disappear sooner or later, and then the question will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid looping by using the constraint

```
$p : Paciente(diagnostico == "")
```

in rule "sem sintomas 1" as well.

Recommendation: You should use

```
modify( $p ){ setDiagnostico("...") }
```

rather than update.

These id values ("001",...) are strange: they don't identify a symptom, and they don't identify patients because then they wouldn't be stored along with a symptom. Normally, one identifies symptoms with a key (e.g. ICD-10), and patients would have a list of symptom keys. Then, a rule can determine the disease from the presence and absence of symptoms.

I'm not sure what your ids are meant to identify. The heavy use of salience throughout is an indication that something isn't right. You should be able to do this with a (low) salience only in the last rule to print the result for each patient.